# How to access table attribute from Model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I want to write few methods in Model of my application which modifies the data received from the Form and then stores in database. How do I access attributes of table in model? How do I set default value of 'status' column as 'active'?
For e.g consider my form has three columns first_name, last_name and Age. Now I want to access this attributes from Model, split Name (received by Form) to first_name and last_name  and modify age (lets say add by 10% of original age) and then save new 'age' and first_name and last_name into database.. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name=(a_name)
    self.first_name, self.last_name = a_name.split ','
  end

  def age=(an_age)
     self.age = an_age.to_i * 1.1
  end
end

sm = SomeModel.new
sm.name = 'FirstName, LastName'
sm.age = 10
sm.save
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this way

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :is_admin

  def is_admin
    self.status = 'f' unless self.status
  end
end
```